# Being+past participle

Tags: participle-clauses

should we use 'being' with past participle' when we want to give reson for the action in the main clause? For example

For example,

> Being offered a visa for USA, I'm going to go there.
>   (since/because I was offered a visa, I . . . )
>
> He Being employed in teaching at a school, he could hardly manage time for painting.
>   (because/since he was employed,he could. . . .)

can we can use"being+p.p" in both past and present situation(As above sentences)?

Comment: #3 and #4 should be **have gotten** instead of **have got**.

Comment: @jtbandes BrE uses *got* as the past participle. AmE uses *gotten* as the past participle, so they are equally correct.

Comment: @jtbandes, nope, according to the rules of English, it must be got (unless you are an american)

Comment: I wonder why it's so delayed to answer this question!